# Relationship between frequency and amplitude of mechanical waves

Tags: waves

Can two mechanical waves carry same energy whose frequencies are different?(assuming same medium but having different amplitudes

Answer (score 1):

If you consider a mechanical wave in a string, that is possible as long as you keep $\omega A$ fixed.

That is because the energy of a mechanical wave is given by

$I = \frac{1}{2}\rho v\omega^2A^2$

Many textbooks would contain a proof, and http://cnx.org/content/m12793/latest/ may help as well.